# how to read xml parse in jquery and display in html element

Tags: jquery, html, xml, parsing, service

I'm trying to display parsed xml data in html. I have already successfully called data from web service and set the dataType to xml. However the code below has no error, it is not displaying parsed xml data to html. What am I doing wrong?

The XML data:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<string>
    <DriverInfo xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/DriverInfo.xsd\">
        <Driver>
            <ID>-1</ID>
                <driver_code>DRIVER01</driver_code>
                <driver_name>DRIVER01 Name</driver_name>
            <transtamp>2017-02-16T14:41:09.9655914+08:00</transtamp>
        </Driver>
    </DriverInfo>
</string>
```

The whole code that has successfully retrieved the XML data parsed:

```
$.ajax({
    url: domainName + "GetDriverXml", 
    method: "GET",
    data: {wsCodeCrypt:"MULARIDEWS", caUid: "mularide", caPwd:"VAt_-tg4%Z5pcpct", 
    driverCode:"DRIVER01"},
    cache: false,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML($(data).text());
            var $xml = $(xmlDoc);

            var $driver = $xml.find("Driver");

            $driver.each(function(){

            var driverCode = $(this).find('driver_code').text(),
                driverName = $(this).find('driver_name').text();

            $("#driverDet" ).append('<li>' +driverCode+ ' - ' +driverName+ '</li>');

            });         
    }          
});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="driverDet"></ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Found the problem as pointed out by madalin ivascu, 'driver' needs to be changed to 'Driver'. Also updated code that parses 'data' as .text, then there is light!

Comment: can you post the xml?

Comment: I have added the xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change driver to Driver in your find selector

```
var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' ?><string><DriverInfo xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/DriverInfo.xsd\"> <Driver><ID>-1</ID><driver_code>DRIVER01</driver_code><driver_name>DRIVER01 Name</driver_name><transtamp>2017-02-16T14:41:09.9655914+08:00</transtamp></Driver><Driver><ID>-1</ID><driver_code>DRIVER01</driver_code><driver_name>DRIVER01 Name</driver_name><transtamp>2017-02-16T14:41:09.9655914+08:00</transtamp></Driver></DriverInfo></string>",
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
$(xmlDoc).find('Driver').each(function() {
  var driverCode = $(this).find('driver_code').text(),
    driverName = $(this).find('driver_name').text();

  $("#ProfileList").append('<li>' + driverCode + ' - ' + driverName + '</li>');

});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/814yhL3m/

Comment: That was indeed a typo on my end. I have found the solution as to why the var $driver failed to grab the value of data. The XML data needs to be parsed as ($(data).text()). It works now. I will update the code. Thanks.